# Devise Invitable throws 401 UnAuthorized error after invitation is accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am using Rails 4.1.14, Ruby 2.1.6, Devise 3.2.4 and Devise_invitable 1.3.6.

The issue I am having is once a new user I invited presses the accept invitation link in the email they received, it gets stuck in a redirect loop. I can't figure out why.

These are the server logs for the entire operation (note that the bulk of the first part of the log corresponds to the logic I omit below - but I left it in case it tells something interesting) :

```
Started GET "/users/invitation/accept?invitation_token=qANzitr64dxzxG9dSsMU" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-12 04:51:29 -0500
Processing by Users::InvitationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"invitation_token"=>"qANzitr6"}
  User Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."invitation_token" = 'qANzitr6'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Member Load (3.8ms)  SELECT  "members".* FROM "members"  WHERE "members"."email" = 'def@test.com' LIMIT 1
  Membership Load (88.3ms)  SELECT  "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."member_id" = 115 LIMIT 1
  Connection Load (14.8ms)  SELECT  "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."membership_id" = 173  ORDER BY "connections"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (2.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.4ms)  UPDATE "memberships" SET "invited_id" = $1, "member_id" = $2, "relative_type" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "memberships"."id" = 173  [["invited_id", 83], ["member_id", nil], ["relative_type", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-12-12 09:51:30.038439"]]
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
  Membership Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = $1 AND "memberships"."invited_id" = 83  ORDER BY "memberships"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  FamilyTree Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 83]]
  Membership Load (3.7ms)  SELECT  "memberships".* FROM "memberships"  WHERE "memberships"."user_id" = 83 AND "memberships"."invited_id" = 1 AND "memberships"."family_tree_id" = 85 AND "memberships"."relation" = 'wife' AND "memberships"."relative_type" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (33.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (37.9ms)  INSERT INTO "memberships" ("created_at", "family_tree_id", "invited_id", "relation", "relative_type", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-12-12 09:51:30.105734"], ["family_tree_id", 85], ["invited_id", 1], ["relation", "wife"], ["relative_type", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-12-12 09:51:30.105734"], ["user_id", 83]]
  Connection Exists (11.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "connections" INNER JOIN "memberships" ON "memberships"."id" = "connections"."membership_id" WHERE (memberships.invited_id = 83) LIMIT 1
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
   (1.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.7ms)  UPDATE "connections" SET "invited_membership_id" = $1, "invited_user_id" = $2, "request_status" = $3, "responded_at" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "connections"."id" = 127  [["invited_membership_id", 174], ["invited_user_id", 83], ["request_status", 1], ["responded_at", "2015-12-12 09:51:30.167563"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-12 09:51:30.172215"]]
   (1.9ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (2.3ms)  DELETE FROM "members" WHERE "members"."id" = 115
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (4.5ms)
  Rendered users/invitations/edit.html.erb within layouts/devise (48.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1689ms (Views: 1405.9ms | ActiveRecord: 222.2ms)


Started PUT "/users/invitation" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-12 04:51:53 -0500
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"invitation_token"=>"qANzitr6", "gender"=>"female", "invitation_relation"=>"wife", "full_name"=>"My Wife", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Register", "id"=>"invitation"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-12 04:51:53 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"login"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-12 04:51:53 -0500
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"login"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

This is my `Users::InvitationsController#Edit`

```
def edit
  # Some logic that I know works and is irrelevant to this question.

  # below is lifted directly from the `edit` action within the gem itself.
  set_minimum_password_length if respond_to? :set_minimum_password_length
  resource.invitation_token = params[:invitation_token]
  render :edit

end
```

Then I specified an `accept_resource` method like [the docs](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#configuring-controllers) suggested I do if I want anything special to happen after or before the invitation is sent.

```
def accept_resource
  resource = resource_class.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)
  resource.confirm!
  resource
end
```

I assumed that part of the reason this must be happening is that I am stuck in a loop where the user's account wasn't confirmed after they accepted....hence that override.

Here is my `User.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable, :confirmable
end
```

What could be causing this?